# Reusing initializer method when calling base constructor

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I want to initialize a protected member in a derived class using the constructor, but since I am calling base() I can't call this(), which makes some of my calls "smell":

```
public class ABase
    {
        public object Param1 { get; set; }
        public object Param2 { get; set; }
        protected object Param3 { get; set; }

        public ABase()
            : this(null, null)
        { }

        public ABase(object param1)
            : this(param1, null)
        { }

        public ABase(object param1, object param2)
        {
            Param1 = param1;
            Param2 = param2;
        }
    }

    public class A : ABase
    {
        public A()
        { InitParam3(); }

        public A(object param1)
            : base(param1)
        { InitParam3(); }

        public A(object param1, object param2)
            : base(param1, param2)
        { InitParam3(); }

        private void InitParam3()
        {
            Param3 = "param3";
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid calling `InitParam3()` in every constructor. I'm open to design changes altogether.

Comment: Current solution (your code) is better than @lazyberezovsky answer. See my comment.

Comment: Question states as 'Is there a way to avoid calling InitParam3() in every constructor'.

Comment: I actually have to agree with both of you, but each solution has its own drawbacks.

Comment: See my updated solution without default values duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use constructors chain for child class and call to most full constructor of base class then.

```
    public class ABase
        {
            public object Param1 { get; set; }
            public object Param2 { get; set; }
            protected object Param3 { get; set; }

            public ABase()
                : this(null, null)
            { }

            public ABase(object param1)
                : this(param1, null)
            { }

            public ABase(object param1, object param2)
            {
                Param1 = param1;
                Param2 = param2;
            }
        }

        public class A : ABase
        {
            public A() : this(null, null)
            { }

            public A(object param1)
                : this(param1m, null)
            { }

            public A(object param1, object param2)
                : base(param1, param2)
            { InitParam3(); }

            private void InitParam3()
            {
                Param3 = "param3";
            }
        }
```

UPDATE (Duplication of default values removed):

```
public abstract class ABase
{
    protected const object DefaultParam1 = null;
    protected const object DefaultParam2 = null;

    public object Param1 {get;set;}
    public object Param2 { get; set; }
    protected object Param3 { get; set; }

    public ABase(object param1 = DefaultParam1, object param2 = DefaultParam2)
    {
        Param1 = param1;
        Param2 = param2;
    }
}

public class A : ABase
{
    public A(object param1 = DefaultParam1, object param2 = DefaultParam2)
        : base(param1, param2)
    {
        Param3 = "param3";
    }       
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the derived Class is making the same assumptions super class is doing while it has to leave it for the super-class. Super-class uses `null` to initiate and if you change your decision to use a different default other than `null`, you have to change 2 places.

Comment: Yes, but it's the only way to remove duplication of protected parameters initialization.

Comment: Other solution is to call virtual initializer in base constructor, but it's the worst solution, because overridden initializer could refer some child class fields which are not yet initialized.

Comment: I would argue that you should *always* chain public constructors using `this` and use one single constructor to call the base class. It guarantees consistent behaviour between the constructors and makes it much easier to maintain.

Comment: Duplication always can be removed. I've added constants for default values AND new c# 4 feature to generate constructors chain.

Answer (score 1):

No.

This is an OK solution.

The problem with lazyberezovsky's approach is that the derived Class is making its own assumptions for default value of parameters while it has to leave it for the super-class.

Super-class uses null to initiate and if you change your decision to use a different default other than null, you have to change 2 places.

**For me, decision on default value is more important than the minor duplication.**